# Cleaning rows of special characters and creating dataframe columns

Tags: python, data-cleaning

Below is my Dataframe format consisting of 2 columns (one is index and other is the data to be cleaned)

```
 0  ans({'A,B,C,Bad_QoS,Sort'})
 1  ans({'A,B,D,QoS_Miss1,Sort'})
```

1. I want to remove special characters
2. create a data frame for all comma separated items.

I have managed to first remove ***ans*** from all rows using:

```
ds_[col2] = ds_.replace('ans', '', regex=True)

> 0 ({'A,B,C,Bad_QoS,Sort'})
> 1 ({'A,B,D,QoS_Miss1,Sort'})
```

Then I try to apply replace regex, see below:

```
ds_['col2'] = ds_['col2'].str.replace( r' \(\{\' | \'\}\) ', '', regex=True)
ds_['col2']
```

I get no errors, but no changes.

How could I clean these characters and also create a data frame like below:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4  col5  col6 

0    A    B    C    Bad_Qos  Sort
1    A    B    D    Qos_Miss1 Sort
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first split on `'`, and then on `,` and then remove unnecessary columns:

first

```
df[['col_21','col_22','col_23']] = df['col2'].str.split("'",expand=True)
```

and

```
df[['col_2','col_3','col_4','col_5','col_6']] = df['col_22'].str.split(",",expand=True)
```

finally remove rest.

Comment: Thank you, it worked beautifully :)

Comment: Cant upvote as I am new to the forum.

Comment: @Tarzan you can probably accept as correct but don't worry about it.

Comment: I am not able to accept the answer as well. Don't see that option. Someone please accept the answer for me. thanks.